# Javascript RegEx Help

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, client-side-validation

Can someone help me to validate the following rules using a RegEx pattern

Max length : 15
Minimum length : 6
Minimum character count : 1
Minimum numbers count : 1
Consequent repeated character count : 2

Comment: This is probably possible, but will produce very complicated and hard to understand regex (you will have 2 problems: one problem with validating, second with complicated regex). Why not simple function with those checks?

Comment: I have already implemented a validation mechanism. But I'm not much comfortable with the RegEx pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^                   # start of string
(?=.{6,15}$)        # assert length
(?=.*[A-Za-z])      # assert letter
(?=.*[0-9])         # assert digit
(?:(.)(?!\1\1))*    # assert no more than 2 consecutive characters
$                   # end of string
```

will do this. But this won't look nice (or easily maintainable) in JavaScript:

```
if (/^(?=.{6,15}$)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?:(.)(?!\1\1))*$/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I have looked for.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a few different regex patterns to check for all those rules cause it will either be impossible or very complicated.

- `.length` to check the first 2 rules
- `[a-z]` (with case insensitive option) for the 3rd rule
- `\d` for the 4th rule
- `(.)\1{2,}` for the 5th rule, if this one matches the string contains 3+ character repetitions

Comment: The last one won't catch a password like `a0!!!!`. Also, `\a-z` is invalid, you probably mean `[a-z]`.

Comment: @Tim, corrected my answer even tho yours has already been accepted